# IOS UIColor in struct

Tags: objective-c

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mauris nibh, venenatis sed purus nec, consequat commodo turpis. Quisque rhoncus maximus mattis. Morbi convallis sagittis lectus eget mollis. Nunc tristique, lectus ac faucibus elementum, dui enim porta ex, nec vestibulum sem neque sit amet est. Donec massa arcu, fermentum a massa eu, maximus rutrum urna. Vestibulum imperdiet pulvinar ipsum, non imperdiet orci efficitur quis. Donec volutpat erat dui, a sodales enim blandit ut. Pellentesque ac imperdiet nibh, sed feugiat lorem. Praesent in velit et est tempus facilisis sed at urna. Nulla sapien sem, sagittis eu mauris quis, consequat tempor sem. Mauris rhoncus, turpis eu vehicula volutpat, nibh libero fermentum quam, vel posuere ante metus quis leo. Maecenas et lorem feugiat neque lobortis accumsan.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the opaque type [`CGColorRef`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html) instead of `UIColor` on your struct. Then, in the CocoaTouch portion of your code you could get a `UIColor` instance like this:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:colorRef];
```

Comment: You will still have to manage life-time of CGColorRef instance manually somehow...

Comment: @Vladimir: yes. or you can use `CGColor` structure directly.

Comment: what I mean this approach will remove compiler error, but you're responsible for retaining/releasing CGColorRef field manually - so your approach does not actually solve the root problem with memory management here

Comment: @Vladimir: you don't retain/release `CGColor` or `CGColorRef` since they're not objective-c classes in the first place. They're just plain old C structure and pointer respectively.

Comment: no :) You need to maintain CGColorRef lifetime with CGColorRetain and CFRelease functions, much like you do retain/release with obj-c objects. Try this sample controller code: https://gist.github.com/3879160 it will crash without CGColorRetain call (and with that call it will leak CGColorRef)

Comment: how is this any better than `__unsafe_unretained UIColor` as the OP already found?

Answer (score 0):

I saves you some hassle if you follow that advice of not mixing structs and objects. That leaves you with two possibilities:

1. Using Objective-C objects: Make "LevelMeterColorThreshold" a class with two properties instead of a struct.
2. Use C structs and C primitives: Instead of "UIColor" use three floats red/green/blue - if that is sufficient. Then you can reconstruct a UIColor later on.

I probably would pick #1.

Comment: I completely agree with Carsten

Answer (score 0):

How is it possible that in this example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Listings/AudioViews_LevelMeter_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802-AudioViews_LevelMeter_h-DontLinkElementID_7

they are using the struct with UIColor*?